# Beginner questions about c#

Tags: c#

1) Can Ι add a string with a int ?

2) Why we put f at the float type numbers and l at long type numbers ?

3) Is there any difference between anArray[2] and anArray.GetValue(3) ? Why to use the second 
one ?

4) If I use a Counter at a "for" type loop, it is better to declare the counter at the start of the program or at every loop ?

Comment: These should be separate questions.

Comment: Please ask each question separately, and provide information about your research.

Comment: and note that most of those question are duplicate that you can find here on stackoverflow or with a simple search on google

Comment: From your above question, I think you are a very beginner to c#. I recommend you to watch videos on the link below : http://www.youtube.com/kudvenkat

Comment: One bunch of questions as one was excusable for a beginner. You were asked to post as separate questions though. As this is a repeat offence, you get a downvote and a vote to close. Please read the comments against your questions and you'll have a more rewarding experience with SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can Ι add a string with a int ?

No, you have to use casting: `int result = Int32.Parse("10") + 10;`

> Why we put f at the float type numbers and l at long type numbers ?

A way to indicate the type of the variable value in order to prevent confusion: The right-hand side is evaluated on its own. According to the C# specification, a number containing a decimal point that doesn't have a suffix is interpreted as a double.

> Is there any difference between anArray[2] and anArray.GetValue(3)
>   ? Why to use the second one ?

In the given case, they are both the same, just take on account that `GetValue()` have multiple overloads in order to let you get elements data from multidimensional arrays.

> If I use a Counter at a "for" type loop, it is better to declare
>   the counter at the start of the program or at every loop ?

For each loop, even nested one, you should declare a separate counter (`i`). Take a look at this example:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
      for(int j = 0; j < 100; j++)
      {
        Console.Write(i * j);            
      }
    }
```

Comment: About the last i didnt mean that. In your example the i if it is used at 2 or 3 loops is better the declare it in every loop like what you did or at the start of the method ?

Comment: @user2936672 I suppose you're talking about nested loops. In every loop you should declare a new counter. see my update.